# Не работает gulp-dirty-markup

Tags: html, gulp, pug

Pug компилирует html в одну строку:

```
<html><head><title>title</title></head><body><div><p>123</p><p>456</p><p>789</p><p>456</p><p>aaa</p><p>bbb</p><p>252</p><p>333</p><p>444</p><p>777</p><p>888</p><p>ddd</p></div></body></html>
```

Нашел плагин который вроде как должен добавлять отступы для читабельности, по крайней мере сайт есть для этого с [таким же названием](https://dirtymarkup.com/).
Вот мой gulpfile, может я где-то неправильно что-то написал, но в папке output появляется всё тот же html-файл без отступов, что и в папке app. Ну и [страница плагина](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-dirty-markup).

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
pug = require('gulp-pug'),
sass = require('gulp-sass'),
less = require('gulp-less'),
dirtymarkup = require('gulp-dirty-markup'),
browserSync = require('browser-sync'),
reload = browserSync.reload,
autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
paths = {
  pug:['app/pug/*.pug'],
  less:['app/less/*.less'],
  sass:['app/sass/*.scss'],
  dirtymarkup:['app/*.html']
};

//Pug
gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.pug)
        .pipe(pug())
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});

// Less
/*gulp.task('less', function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.less)
        .pipe(less())
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});
*/
// Sass
gulp.task('sass', function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.sass)
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(autoprefixer(['last 15 versions', '> 1%'], { cascade: true }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/css'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});

// Dirtymarkup
gulp.task('dirtymarkup', function() {
    gulp.src(paths.dirtymarkup)
        .pipe(dirtymarkup({ indent: 'auto' }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app/output'));
});

// Browser-Sync
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
      baseDir: 'app'
    },
    open: true,
    notify: false
  });
});

gulp.task('watcher',function(){
  gulp.watch(paths.pug, ['pug']);
  gulp.watch(paths.sass, ['sass']);
  gulp.watch(paths.dirtymarkup, ['dirtymarkup']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watcher', 'browserSync']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Не нужен вам этот плагин. Чтобы компилировать читаемый `HTML`, ваш таcк по сборке нужно немного изменить:

```
gulp.task('pug', function(){
    return gulp.src(paths.pug)
        .pipe(pug({
            pretty: true; // Эта строка скомпилирует красивый HTML
         }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('app'))
        .pipe(reload({stream: true}))
});
```